# Check whether or not a booking is possible

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm currently implementing a booking system. The seller can specify how many items of the given type are available. The rule is simple: There can never be more bookings then available items.

Now I would like to find out with how many existing bookings a new booking is in conflict in order to check if the limit is reached.

The following diagram should give you a little insight on what I'm trying to do.

https://ibb.co/4pJk8XV

In this example the maximum amount of concurrent bookings is 2. As you can see there are already 3 bookings. One of which has no end date specified.
Only viewing the existing bookings there are never more than 2 bookings at the time.

Now I would like to check whether a new booking is possible. I know the start date for every booking. For bookings with no specified end date, the end date will be null.

I'm trying to achieve this using Mongoose.

There is no existing code regarding this problem.

Looking at each example separately: The first one with no end date should fail, since between the 07th and 09th there would be 3 bookings at a time. The second one should be fine as there is only one existing booking on the 06th.

Answer (score 0):

We will start by finding all intersections with the newDocument i'm only going to make one assumption which is that the "`newBooking`" `endDate` is typed `date` (if its null then we make it a very far futuristic date)

```
let newBookingStartDate = newBooking.startDate;
let newBookingEndDate = newBooking.endDate ? newBooking.endDate : new Date().setYear(3000);
```

Now for the query:

```
let results = await db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            tmpEndDate: {
                $cond: [
                    {$ne: ["$endDate", null]},
                    "$endDate",
                    newBookingEndDate
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                  {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            startDate: {$lt: newBookingStartDate},
                        },
                        {
                            tmpEndDate: {$gt: newBookingStartDate}
                        },
                    ]
                },

                {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            startDate: {$gte: newBookingStartDate},
                        },
                        {
                            startDate: {$lt: newBookingEndDate}
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ],
        }
    },
])
```

We match documents by diving into two cases:

1. `document.startDate` is lower than `newDocument.startDate` - in this case all we need to check if the `document.endDate` is greater then the `newDocument.startDate`, if it is then we have an intersection
2. `document.startDate` is greater or equal to `newDocument.startDate` - in this case we just need to check the `document.startDate` is less than the `newDocument.endDate` and again we'll get an intersection

Now we need to iterate over the documents we found and calculate intersections between them by running the same query:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        let doc = results[i];
        let otherIds = results.map(val => val._id);

        let docStartDate = doc.startDate;
        let docEndDate = doc.endDate ? doc.endDate : new Date().setYear(3000);
        let count = await db.collection.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    _id: {$in: otherIds}
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    tmpEndDate: {
                        $cond: [
                            {$ne: ["$endDate", null]},
                            "$endDate",
                            docEndDate
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    $or: [
                        {
                            $and: [
                                {
                                    startDate: {$lt: docStartDate},
                                },
                                {
                                    tmpEndDate: {$gt: docStartDate}
                                },
                            ]
                        },

                        {
                            $and: [
                                {
                                    startDate: {$gte: docStartDate},
                                },
                                {
                                    startDate: {$lt: docEndDate}
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                    ],

                }
            },
            {
                $count: "count"
            }
        ])
      if (count[0].count >= 3){
            return false;
      }
    }
```

If any of the count results is 3 or greater (3 because i didn't remove the curr document ID from the array and it will always intersect with itself) return false as inserting a new document will set you over the threshold.

Comment: Hey, sound like a good start. But I think it is not enough to find intersections, is it? For example if there are 2 existing bookings which each have an intersection with the new booking (one at the start date one at the end date) the above code would return 2. If we know say that we can only have 2 bookings at a time the booking would not be possible. But the truth is that the booking would be possible since there are never more then 2 bookings at any time.

Comment: you are correct, i edited my answer to be correct accordingly